# Merge dot notation key string to Object

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I'm stumped. I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "sys": {
        "subject": "",
        "preview_text": "",
        "show_view_in_browser": true,
        "email_webview_url": "",
        "rep_alert": true,
        "signatures": {
            "show_joshua": true,
            "show_warren": true,
            "show_david": true
        },
        "email_address": "",
        "show_unsub_link": true,
        "unsubscribe_link": ""
    },
    "pre_intro": {
        "content__rtf": ""
    },
    "pre_intro.button__group": [
        {
            "url": "",
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        }
    ],
    "content": {
        "introduction__rtf": "",
        "investor-returns": {
            "intro__rtf": "",
            "img__href": "",
            "end__rtf": ""
        },
        "end__rtf": ""
    },
    "content.investor-returns.button__group": [
        {
            "url": "",
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        }
    ],
    "content.button__group": [
        {
            "url": "",
            "name": "",
            "img": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see I have `pre_intro` and `pre_intro.button__group` as well as some other keys that are dot notations.  How do I break these down so they are merged into this object so the output would be:

```
"pre_intro": {
  "content__rtf": "",
  "button__group": [
    {  
      "url": "",
      "name": "",
      "img": ""
    }
  ]
},
```

I've tried to use lodash's `_.pickBy()` to get all keys that include `'.'`, then tried to reduce them into an object, but could not get that to work.

```
_.pickBy(snippets, function(v, k) {
    return _.includes(k, ".");
});

const ref = (obj, str) => {
    return str.split(".").reduce(function(o, x) { return o[x] }, obj);
}
```

Any help with this?  I have no control over the original object I am given.

Comment: do you have nested keys with dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any external libraries to help solve this issue, here is an algorithm using vanilla Javascript:

1- Find all keys that contain `.`.

2- split the key into a parent, and child

3- assign a new sub-key to the parent key

4- delete the key that contains the `.`

```js
const object = {
  "sys": {
    "subject": "",
    "preview_text": "",
    "show_view_in_browser": true,
    "email_webview_url": "",
    "rep_alert": true,
    "signatures": {
      "show_joshua": true,
      "show_warren": true,
      "show_david": true
    },
    "email_address": "",
    "show_unsub_link": true,
    "unsubscribe_link": ""
  },
  "pre_intro": {
    "content__rtf": ""
  },
  "pre_intro.button__group": [{
    "url": "",
    "name": "",
    "img": ""
  }],
  "content": {
    "introduction__rtf": "",
    "investor-returns": {
      "intro__rtf": "",
      "img__href": "",
      "end__rtf": ""
    },
    "end__rtf": ""
  },
  "content.investor-returns.button__group": [{
    "url": "",
    "name": "",
    "img": ""
  }],
  "content.button__group": [{
    "url": "",
    "name": "",
    "img": ""
  }]
};

Object.keys(object).filter(key => key.indexOf(".") >= 0).forEach(key => {
  const combined = key.split(/\./);
  const parent = combined[0];
  const child = combined[1];
  if(!object[parent]) object[parent] = {}; // in case the key doesn't exist yet 

  object[parent][child] = object[key];  // assign the value.
  delete object[key];                   // remove the ugly key
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`flat` from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat), then do this:

```
import { flatten, unflatten } from 'flat';

const v = { ...yourobject }

const merged = unflatten(flatten(v));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a new object the first level of keys.

```js
const
    convert = source => Object
        .entries(source)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
            const
                keys = k.split('.'),
                last = keys.pop();

            keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, r)[last] = v;
            return r;
        }, {}),
    data = { sys: { subject: "", preview_text: "", show_view_in_browser: true, email_webview_url: "", rep_alert: true, signatures: { show_joshua: true, show_warren: true, show_david: true }, email_address: "", show_unsub_link: true, unsubscribe_link: "" }, pre_intro: { content__rtf: "" }, "pre_intro.button__group": [{ url: "", name: "", img: "" }], content: { introduction__rtf: "", "investor-returns": { intro__rtf: "", img__href: "", end__rtf: "" }, end__rtf: "" }, "content.investor-returns.button__group": [{ url: "", name: "", img: "" }], "content.button__group": [{ url: "", name: "", img: "" }] },
    result = convert(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```